# Visual Studio: Cannot resolve event / custom event tooltip

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, resharper

Odd that I can't find anyone else that has encountered this issue.

In Visual Studio I have a few custom events that I fire and listen to between applications on the same page. The event names aren't important but here they are: 'dd.clear', 'dd.select', 'dd.switch'.

I get a tooltip warning "Cannot resolve event 'dd.clear'". How can I fix this? I can use Resharper's inspection tool to disable it but I'd like a better solution. Can I define my custom events somewhere and if so how?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add some codes?

Comment: Added a screenshot of the issue with the relevant code.

Comment: Please add code as text. Pictures of code are not useful. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @AdrianHHH, in this case, it is useful as the code has nothing to do with the problem only the error message.

Comment: If the code has nothing to do with the problem then why have you added even a picture of it?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio basic JavaScript Snippets seems not to know custom events. **Install [vscode-standardjs-snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=capaj.vscode-standardjs-snippets)** and you should be fine.

**Note** that this `tooltip` warning is nothing realy important. It does not mean that your codes are broken.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I did look into this and it does solve my issue while I'm using vs code, however, the problem I'm trying to resolve is with Visual Studio (specifically 2017).

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came through is to use the actual type property of the event object :

```
class Model extends EventTarget {
    static topicChangedEvent = new Event("topicChanged");

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.topic = "";
    }

    setTopic(topic) {
        if (this.topic === topic)
            return;

        this.topic = topic;
        this.dispatchEvent(Model.topicChangedEvent);
    }
}

const model = new Model();

/* ... */

model.addEventListener(Model.topicChangedEvent.type, () => ...);
```